# C# Visual Studio - Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs could not be found

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I started a C# Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2012. I added some shapes, and I think they are from a Visual Basic pack.

That was at school. At home I have Visual Studio 2015, and I thought I would continue with my project at home, but that's a problem, because when I open the solution and the project in Visual Studio 2015 I get many errors like this:

> The referenced component 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs' could not be found.

So I installed the `VB Powerpack`, but that didn't help.

Comment: try this https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25169

Comment: If the `VB Powerpack` is listed in your project references, try setting the `localcopy` to `true`

Comment: @Pim Every time I set it to true, it changes back to false, even after installing VB Powerpacks from Pranav's link

Comment: @MatějZíka I'm not quite sure, but it could mean that the `.dll` is already listed within your GAC (Global Assembly Cache) and that somethin is wrong there, but I don't know to much about that.

Answer (score 0):

That package is not included in Visual Studio 2015. You have to download it here (you can find the instructions):

*[VisualBasic PowerPack missing from Visual Studio 2013?](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2013/12/20/visualbasic-powerpack-missing-from-visual-studio-2013/)*